# feeding a list of integers into an sql query to populate a gridview

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm using a session to store a list of itemID's that a user has added to their shopping cart. When the user goes to the 'View cart' page, I want to dnamically populate a gridview with data about the items from an sql database. (eventually with buttons to remove from cart)

I'm currently feeding the itemID's into a string that reads like an SQL statement. Does anyone know that can be used to populate a gridview? Here's the code:

```
//empty Session["cart"] into a list, and step through each itemID, making SQL
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> cartList = new List<int>();
    cartList = (List<int>)Session["cart"];
    string queryString = ("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productID IS ");

    int firstElement = cartList.First();
    int lastElement = cartList.Last();
    foreach (int element in cartList)
    {
        if (element.Equals(firstElement))
        {
            string idString = element.ToString();
            queryString = String.Concat(queryString, idString);
        }
        else if (element.Equals(lastElement))
        {
            string idString = element.ToString();
            queryString = String.Concat(queryString, " OR productID IS " + idString + ";");
        }
        else
        {
            string idString = element.ToString();
            queryString = String.Concat(queryString, " OR productID IS " + idString);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an `IN` query would be more efficient:

```
cartList = (List<int>)Session["cart"];
// get comma-delimited list of IDs (e,g, "1, 2, 3")
string idList = string.Join(", ",cartList);
string queryString = string.Format("SELECT * FROM product WHERE productID IN({0}) ", idList);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I could do it like this, but I'm still unsure how to use that string to populate a gridview. I've done a bit of googling and found that I can access a session directly from SQL. Would SQL be able to iterate through the session if it contains a c# list<string> data type? Really out of my depth here..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a User-Defined Table Type to fill a parameter with a list of values.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntegerList] AS TABLE(
    [value] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

It can be used in a StoredProcedure like a table, e.g. to join with your data to achieve filtering:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Query
    @integers dbo.IntegerList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT p.* from Product p
    JOIN @integers i ON p.productid = i.value
END
```

From within C# it can be called with a DataTable as parameter value.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("IntegerList");
dt.Columns.Add("value", typeof(int));

foreach(var i in cartList) {
    dt.Rows.Add(i);
}

using(var command = Connection.CreateCommand()) {
    command.CommandText = "Query";

    var param = new SqlParameter("@integers", SqlDbType.Structured);
    param.TypeName = "dbo.IntegerList";
    param.Value = dt;
    command.Parameters.Add(param);

    Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The created SQL command will look like this:

```
declare @p dbo.IntegerList
INSERT INTO @p VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @p VALUES(2)

EXEC Query @p
```

Comment: Thanks. I got this to compile without errors. How do you make a datatable appear on a web form?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping the cart in the session, you should probably keep the cart in the database itself, and keep just a cart-id in the session, or even attached to the user, so the user can get the cart from a different browser (say, from their tablet), too.

That way, your query is a simple JOIN, you keep the data for later, if you want to research abandoned carts, and of course - you don't risk the SQL injections your code is susceptible to.